# Delete objects in django and api

Tags: django, api, django-models

I want delete an objects from my model in django and api!
can anyone help me?

The code that i wrote:

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete(request,news_id):
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        News.objects.filter(id=news_id).delete()
        return JsonResponse({'message':'***'},safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'message':'***'},safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete(request,news_id):
if request.method == 'DELETE':
    news = get_object_or_404(News,news_id=news_id)
    news.delete()
    return JsonResponse({'message':'***'},safe=False)
else:
    return JsonResponse({'message':'***'},safe=False)
```